# Zybooks keeps telling me that i have an error in my code with the scanner, but it should be fine?

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have a project due tonight in which we are supposed to calculate the trajectory of the input based on the initial speed inputted. I have finished the code, but it keeps failing to compile due to the scanner, but it should work. I have attached my code below:

```
public class TrajectoryModelingIntro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     double degrees;
     double time;
     double distance;
     double intialSpeed;
     
     System.out.println("Enter an intial speed: ");
     initialSpeed = scanner.nextDouble();
     
     for (degrees = 25.00; degrees < 90.00; degrees += 5.00) {
        time = 2 * initialSpeed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees)) / 9.8;
        distance = initialSpeed * time * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
        System.out.format("At angle " + "%.2f" , degrees);
        System.out.format(" projectile travels " + "%.2f", distance);
        System.out.println(" meters");
     }
        
        scanner.close();

    }

}
```

This is the error message I keep receiving for the code :

```
TrajectoryModelingIntro.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
     ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class TrajectoryModelingIntro
TrajectoryModelingIntro.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
                        ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class TrajectoryModelingIntro
TrajectoryModelingIntro.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
     initialSpeed = scnr.nextDouble();
     ^
  symbol:   variable initialSpeed
  location: class TrajectoryModelingIntro
TrajectoryModelingIntro.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        time = 2 * initialSpeed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees)) / 9.8;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable initialSpeed
  location: class TrajectoryModelingIntro
TrajectoryModelingIntro.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        distance = initialSpeed * time * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
                   ^
  symbol:   variable initialSpeed
  location: class TrajectoryModelingIntro
5 errors
```

If anyone has any advice or suggestions, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You have two main bugs I can see, first you have a typo with `double intialSpeed` (should be `initial`, which is what you used in the loop). Second, you missed the `java.util.Scanner` `import` which you can omit by using the fully qualified class name. Also, I would strongly urge you to declare and assign in one statement **and** to use a `try-with-Resources` instead of explicitly closing your `Scanner`. Finally, you can combine all of your outputs into a single statement (and you probably shouldn't use `String` concatenation with formatted output). Like,

```
try (java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("Enter an initial speed: ");
    double initialSpeed = scanner.nextDouble();

    for (double degrees = 25.00; degrees < 90.00; degrees += 5.00) {
        double time = 2 * initialSpeed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees)) / 9.8;
        double distance = initialSpeed * time * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
        System.out.printf("At angle %.2f projectile travels %.2f meters%n",
                degrees, distance);
    }
}
```